# How to pass context data in success_url?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have made a form where i wish to return to the same form again, this time with context data that can be used in my template to show that the form has been successfully sent.

How can i do this?

```
class ContactUsView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactUsForm
    template_name = 'website/pages/contact_us.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super(ContactUsView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Something here?
```

So basically i want `get_success_url` to return to the `ContactUsView` with e.g. `{'success':'true'}` which i can read in the template and render a box that says it has been successfull. I dont want to change to another static page!

Comment: try this `return reverse('url_name', kwargs={'pk': pk})`

Comment: I did not exactly want to pass a kwarg as i then will have to alter my url pattern for that page. That seems a little overkill. I just want to pass some variable to context instead. If i use your method it wont work straight away in any case without altering things: `Reverse for 'ContactUsView' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': '12'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['contact/$']`

Comment: you can use a optional parameter in url for this case. give your `urls.py`.

Comment: url(r'^contact/$', ContactUsView.as_view(), name="ContactUsView"),

Comment: add a url like this :
`url(r'^contact/(?P<success>\w+)$', ContactUsView.as_view(), name="ContactUsView"),`
and change your view like this :
`def ContactUsView(success=None):`

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with class-based views?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth). may help you about `class-based` view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a url like this to `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^contact/(?P<success>\w+)$', ContactUsView.as_view(), name="ContactUsView"),
```

And you can access to this parameter in `class-based` view like this:

add `get_context_data` method to your `class-view`

```
class ContactUsView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'my_var'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactUsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['success'] = self.success
        return context
```

And you can use `{{ my_var.success }}` in your template.

Comment: Now the question is, how i get the template to detect/parse the `success` kwarg?

Answer (score 3):

The `success_url` approach [uses a redirect](https://github.com/django/django/blob/be63c78760924e1335603c36babd0ad6cfaea3c4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L65), which implies you need to pass any additional context data as url parameters, as described in [hasan-ramezani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484591).

An alternative would be **not** to use `success_url` at all:

Instead, you could override `form_valid()` so it returns a `TemplateResponse` instead of an `HTTPResponseRedirect`, following the example of [form_invalid()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/be63c78760924e1335603c36babd0ad6cfaea3c4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L69). Something similar is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567038).

This way, there is no need to modify your `urls.py`.

For example:

```py
class ContactUsView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactUsForm
    template_name = 'website/pages/contact_us.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Render the form again, with current form data and custom context."""
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        context['success'] = True
        context['whatever'] = 'some other custom context'
        return self.render_to_response(context=context)
```