# django createview with success_url being the same view?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a Django CreateView and I wanted to set the `success_url` to the same view so that when the form is posted, it displays the same page and I can display the created object in addition to the form in case you want to add a new one. However, `self.object` is None because of this in `BaseCreateView`:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am concluding that a CreateView is not made to be redisplayed after success?

Comment: You could use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) instead so that the user can add numerous objects via the same form before sumbitting. There is a good library that adds class based views for this sort of functionality called [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong place.

I have to override `form_valid` to not redirect to the URL (`return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`)

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()

        # Does not redirect if valid
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

        # Render the template
        # get_context_data populates object in the context 
        # or you also get it with the name you want if you define context_object_name in the class
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need the object being created to redirect to the same URL of the view. I'd use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    success_url = reverse('path.to.your.create.view')
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I do but then in the template I expected `self.object` to have the created object but it is `None` since it is set to None in the post method.

Comment: When you redirect your user to the URL of the form after success, the new view won't have any reference to the object just created because it only holds a reference to the object being created.

If you want to display the last object created you will have to get hold of it manually, for example with a custom get_success_url method (see [doc](https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/views/generic/edit.py#L128) )

Comment: I was actually looking at the wrong place, I actually have to override form_valid. I added the answer to my question.

Comment: I think this solution is more neat. In my case I had to override get_success_url() because Django web server was complaining of circular import on startup when the reverse() was directly assigned to success_url.

Comment: @user3748764 To prevent circular import errors you can use [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy).

Answer (score 1):

So it's 6 years later and I bumped into this problem while working on my project. In case anyone also faces this problem too in the near future here is a simple and easy fix but might not be recommended but it got the job done for me.

By the way I like using `ClassBasedViews`.

In your `views.py` file

```
class MyMode(CreateView):
    model = my_model
    success_url = '/path-to-webpage/'
```

So what I basically did was to hard-code in the path to the web-page under the `success_url` and that got the problem solved.
This works when you are not planning to change your URLpatterns anytime otherwise you will also have to change the URL in the `views.py` file too.