# How to access form data in `FormView.get_success_url()`

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

Currently, I have a form that looks like this:

```
class SelectBoard(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.SelectBoard

    def form_valid(self, form):
        board_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return redirect('leaderboard', board_name=board_name)
```

However, it would be my preference to do the more idiomatic thing, and use `get_success_url`. Something like this:

```
class SelectBoard(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.SelectBoard

    def get_success_url(self):
        form = ???
        board_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return reverse('leaderboard', board_name=board_name)
```

However, the form is not passed to `get_success_url`, and unlike many other pieces of request context (like `self.request`, `self.kwargs`, or `self.object` (in `DetailView`)), the form is not attached as an attribute at any point in the standard `FormView` dispatch sequence. Is there any good way to access cleaned & validated form data in `get_success_url` (that is, without having to access `self.request.POST` or reconstruct the form from scratch)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26483026

Answer (score 11):

You can override `form_valid` method to write form as instance attribute and use `self.form` inside `get_success_url`:

```
class SelectBoard(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.SelectBoard

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
        self.form = form    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        board_name = self.form.cleaned_data['name']
        return reverse('leaderboard', board_name=board_name)
```

Comment: This was one of my thoughts– overriding `get_form` to do the same thing was another one– but it seemed like a shame, since the whole point is to not have to add any extra code to `form_valid`, since the default behavior works great *except* that there's no way to access the form from `get_success_url`

Answer (score 0):

You might set the success_url attribute in form_valid method getting the form field value if it is needed

```
class SelectBoard(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.SelectBoard

    def form_valid(self, form):
        board_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        self.success_url = reverse('leaderboard', board_name=board_name)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Sure, but if I'm writing a `form_valid` method I can just do when I do in my question. I'm trying to avoid that.