# Django CreateView define field without user input

Tags: django

Let's say I have a `CreateArticleView` like the following which extends `CreateView`.

```
class CreateArticleView(CreateView):
    model = ArticleModel
    fields = ['title', 'text']
```

`ArticleModel` actually has *3* fields, though; it also has `category`.

`category` is a url argument, as urls follow the following regex: `127.0.0.1/category/(?P<category>[0-z]+)/articles/new/`.

I need some way to get the `category` from the URL (this has been answered by SO users) and some way to then take that data and put it into my `ArticleModel` instance (this has not).

For instance, let's say a user wants to create an `ArticleModel` entitled, "[Russia's Military Just Bought Five Bottlenose Dolphins and It Won't Say Why](http://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/russia-s-military-just-bought-five-bottlenose-dolphins-it-won-n560471)" with the text, "Wow!"

I'd get the `title` and `text` from the POST (or GET) data and could plug it into the `ArticleModel` with `article = ArticleModel.objects.create(title=title_from_POST, text=text_from_POST)`. However, I'd also need to provide the `category` kwarg for the `ArticleModel`. How would I plug that in?

---

**Please note**: I am not making a website where people can publish articles. The code above is entirely for example. What I'm looking for is some way to get URL variables to class-based functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django class-based view: How do I pass additional parameters to the as\_view method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth)

Comment: @solarissmoke So then how would I plug in the kwarg value when creating my object?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the form_valid method and access url parameters using the self.kwargs dictionary.

Example:

```
class CreateArticleView(CreateView):
    model = ArticleModel
    fields = ['title', 'text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.kwargs['category'] # Access the category or any other url parameters

        return super(CreateArticleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/