# how to use class based views in django

Tags: django

I want to use class based views instead of function based views to display the template.
How to change this code into class based views

> views.py

```
 def homepage(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    products = Product.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-created')
    featured_products = Product.objects.filter(featured=True)
    return render(request,'shop/base.html',{'categories':categories,'product':products,'featured_products':featured_products})

def categories(request,slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category,active=True)
    return render(request,'shop/products_list.html',{'products':products})
```

Comment: This is too broad. Show what you tried and the problems you experienced.

Comment: i want to use class based views instead of this function based method to display the html template

Comment: Yes. You need to have a go, and ask us any *specific* questions about issues you are having with the code you have written.

Answer (score 1):

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html" 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-created')
        context['featured_products'] = Product.objects.filter(featured=True)
        return context
```

To add some extra information beyond that provided by a generic view you should add an extra context [Documentation Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

Checkout this answer on how to pass additional parameters to a class based view [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth/11494666#11494666)