# How can i add my own attribute in django as_view() method?

Tags: django

I want to add my own attribute 'fileName' inside method 'as_view()'

```
path('dialogs/', CodeResponseView.as_view(fileName='Dialogs.py')),
```

Django give's me an arror:

```
TypeError: CodeResponseView() received an invalid keyword 'fileName'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django class-based view: How do I pass additional parameters to the as\_view method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth)

Comment: How is `CodeResponseView` defined? What does it inherit from?

Comment: Yes, sorry i found the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494483/django-class-based-view-how-do-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-as-view-meth . Thx Nalin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what you should do:

> as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class

So add `fileName` as attribute to your class:

```
class CodeResponseView(View):
    fileName = ''

    # rest of view code can now use the fileName attribute

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['file'] = self.fileName
        return context
```

Now, any url pattern passing `fileName` to `as_view()` will work:

```
path('dialogs/', CodeResponseView.as_view(fileName='Dialogs.py')),
path('alerts/', CodeResponseView.as_view(fileName='Alerts.py')),
```

Comment: i want to use one view class for many different files
--
i dont want to use many view classes for many files

Comment: You can still do that, my code shows `fileName=''` so it's a defined attribute, it just initializes it as empty string, but you can set it to any value you want in the `as_view()` method. Now in your url, you can do `.as_view(fileName="Dialogs.py")` and in another one you can do `.as_view(fileName="SomethingElse.py")` and it'll work. You don't need to define a different class for every filename.

Comment: IT WORK!
need to asign, and then use in def as "self.fileName"

Comment: It work only inside def.... I put "Accept answer" and add some commit :) Thx a lot, dirkgroten

Answer (score 3):

you can add your attribute. your in case **'filename'** as in context.

*if you want to pass and use at templates side is help full when you use **DetailView**,**ListView**,**CreateView**,**TemplateView** etc **generic-class-base view***

**there is two way**

---

> **1.** first way is pass argument in as_view function see here not need to pass at view side or view if you have model you can also pass at urls.py in another keyword arguments model=< Your model name >

**urls.py**

```
path('dialogs/', CodeResponseView.as_view(extra_context={'fileName':'Dialogs.py')),
```

Then you can access filename attribute at your template side like

**Your Template file**

`<h1> My file name is : {{ filename }} </h1>`

### Output:

`My file name is Dialogs.py`

---

> **2.** Second way assign extra_context dictionary in your view class where you define at **view.py** file

**urls.py**

```
path('dialogs/', CodeResponseView.as_view()),
```

**views.py** Here you not need to override a **get_context_data** method for pass **filename**

```
class CodeResponseView(DetailView):
    extra_context={'filename':'Your File name'}
    model=models.<model-name> # here your model name
```

Then you can access filename attribute at your template side like

**Your Template file**

`<h1> My file name is : {{ filename }} </h1>`

### Output:

`My file name is Your File name`

---

- Here i put a link of django docs of extra_context and pre-define variable

  1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/

*This stuff may help you let me know it's answer is right or wrong .....*